# android edit text padding "only text not left drawable image"

Tags: java, android, xml, padding

my problem's photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syyms.png)

I wanna add padding to edit text but i want only text padding. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: what do you have tried??

Comment: Post your progress so far

Comment: give padding left so that text can be placed away from  image

Comment: Rounak Lahoti i tried it but it didnt work. android:drawablePadding is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this:-

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="asdasasa@gmail.com"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_drop"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp" />
```

> For drawable Image padding

android:drawablePadding="5dp"

> For TextView padding

android:padding="5dp"